# QML findChild from a different component

Tags: python, qml, pyside2

**The objective**:
I'm writing a Gui front-end for a Matplotlib-based library for nested samples (`pip install anesthetic` if you want to have a look).

**How I would go about it in C++**: My previous experience with QML was a `C++` program, where instead of going into QML to find a canvas to render to, I created a C++ object, registered it in QML's type system, and had it behave as a QtQuick controls widget. As far as I know this is the recommended way of doing things: have all the rendering be done in QML, and have all the business-end-logic in C++.

**THe best approach and why I can't do it**: This approach doesn't work here. AFAIK you can only implement custom QML using C++, and I need for the program to be pure-ish Python (for others to be able to maintain it) some JS is accessible and QML is pretty easy to understand and edit, so I had no objections (C++ was a hard no).

**what I got working**: I have a working implementation of what I want. It was all in one file. So, naturally I wanted to split the canvas to which I'm drawing to into a separate file: `figure.qml`. Trouble is, I can't seem to find the object by that name whenever it's loaded from a separate file (the next step is to use a `Loader`, because the `Figure` is quite clunky).

I have a two-file project with `view.qml` being the root, and a component in `Figure.qml`.
The trouble is, it only works if I load the thing with `objectName: "component"` in `view.qml` and not in `Component.qml`.

So how does one `findChild` in `Pyside` for an objectName that's in a different `.qml` file?

MWE:

**main.py**

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from matplotlib_backend_qtquick.backend_qtquickagg import FigureCanvasQtQuickAgg
from matplotlib_backend_qtquick.qt_compat import QtGui, QtQml, QtCore


def main():
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
    displayBridge = DisplayBridge()
    context = engine.rootContext()                       
    qmlFile = Path(Path.cwd(), Path(__file__).parent, "view.qml")
    engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(str(qmlFile)))
    win = engine.rootObjects()[0]
    if win.findChild(QtCore.QObject, "figure"):
        print('success') # This fails
    app.exec_()
```

**view.qml**

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Windows 2.12

ApplicationWindow{
   Figure {

   }
}
```

**Figure.qml**

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12 
import QtQuick 2.12

Component{
  Rectangle{ 
    objectName: "figure"
  }
}
```

Comment: it's not so clear what are you asking. What does not work - removing `objectName`, nesting the item, whatever else?

Comment: Updated. The issue is that I get a `None` as the result of finding file. It practically forces me to keep the `Component` in `view.qml`, and I was wondering if there was some semantic that I missed.

Comment: first of all it is worth noting that QtQuick doesn't work with "files" but with `QML` items that are arranged in a kind of tree. [QObject::findChild](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild) looks for an item in this tree by the name , that in QML is synonim for `objectName`, so this property is always mandatory (maybe you missed that). Another thing that you can miss is `options` that should be `Qt::FindChildrenRecursively`. another way to 'lose' an child is to load it indirectly, i.e. using Loader or something like that.

Comment: Ok. So anywhere I can find how these options are bound to PySide?

Comment: I guess it should be 1:1, sorry for that, me and Python are not good friends -)

Comment: It's alright. I never actually had this issue in C++, because I usually exposed the functions to QML, rather than got into QML and did the dirty work... The trouble is I can't do that here.

Comment: @AlexPetrosyan please provide a [mre]

Comment: @AlexPetrosyan 1) the components are loaded asynchronously so you cannot find it, 2) you should not access QML elements from python since they just generate this type of inconvenience, 3) you could explain your basic objective (explain in more detail *I'm trying to do some Python-side rendering to a canvas from QML*) already that for me you have an XY problem, 4) provide an MRE to try to help you.

Comment: @eyllanesc, sorry, I haven't asked questions on SO for a while. Thank you for holding off on the "down-arrow". It should be a lot more clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Component`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html) is used to **define** a QML element, it does **not instantiate** it, therefore you cannot access the object. Creating a Figure.qml is equivalent to creating a Component, and you are creating a Component inside another Component.

The solution is not to use Component:

**Figure.qml**

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12 
import QtQuick 2.12

Rectangle{ 
    objectName: "figure"
}
```

But it is not recommended to use objectName since, for example, if you create multiple components, how will you identify which component it is? o If you create the object after a time T, or use Loader or Repeater you will not be able to apply that logic. Instead of them it is better to create a QObject that allows obtaining those objects:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore
import shiboken2


class ObjectManager(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._qobjects = []

    @property
    def qobjects(self):
        return self._qobjects

    @QtCore.Slot(QtCore.QObject)
    def add_qobject(self, obj):
        if obj is not None:
            obj.destroyed.connect(self._handle_destroyed)
            self.qobjects.append(obj)
        print(self.qobjects)

    def _handle_destroyed(self):
        self._qobjects = [o for o in self.qobjects if shiboken2.isValid(o)]
```

```
# ...
object_manager = ObjectManager()
context = engine.rootContext()
context.setContextProperty("object_manager", object_manager)
qmlFile = Path(Path.cwd(), Path(__file__).parent, "view.qml")
engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(str(qmlFile)))
# ...
```

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12 
import QtQuick 2.12

Rectangle{ 
    Component.onCompleted: object_manager.add_qobject(this)
}
```

Comment: @AlexPetrosyan mmm, I don't understand you, explain yourself better

Comment: I didn't see the updated answer. I was wondering how to use loaders, and still be able to obtain the canvas... I'm quite happy that there is a way, and I'm quite happy that it doesn't involve me having to memorise the names and keep everything in top level.